# Google Cloud Storage - Trying to get an Access Token in Elixir

Tags: rest, google-cloud-storage, elixir, oauth2-playground

I'm trying to use [OAuth2 for Elixir](https://github.com/scrogson/oauth2) to get an access token to interact with the Google Cloud Storage API. I've been experimenting with the OAuth2 Playground and I can make the requests and they give me back the token. Upon doing a basic GET request (to list the buckets in the project) it all works correctly, but of course I need to get the token automatically inside my app instead of copy pasting.

```
  def token do 
  client = OAuth2.Client.new([
            strategy: OAuth2.Strategy.AuthCode, #default
            client_id: "myClientID",
            client_secret: "myClientSecret",
            site: "https://www.googleapis.com",
            redirect_uri: "https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground" #I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT SHOULD BE HERE???
  ])

  token =
    client
    |> OAuth2.Client.put_param(:code, "myAuthCode")
    |> OAuth2.Client.get_token!()
```

I keep getting a "Not Found" message.

I'm quite confused by this, if someone could help I'd be most thankful.

EDIT:

Apparently the request should be something like this:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=token&client_id=myClientID&nonce=someRandomStringIthink&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control&redirect_uri=WHEREDOIGETTHIS
```

I still have no idea where to find the Redirect URI. The documentation says it should be in the developer's console.

Comment: The redirect_uri should be the callback URL for your application. You likely specify this when creating your app on Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can check an example for Google Auth [here](https://github.com/lessless/g_cloud_storage/blob/master/lib/auth/access_token.ex). It covers everything you need to interact with gcs.

Comment: Link is dead as of Feb 2021